# Mongo Embedded Document is not JSON Serializable - Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, mongoengine, graphene-python

I am currently using Graphene with MongoEngine. The mongo db schemas are as follows

```
class DocumentAModel(Document):
    id = StringField(required=True)
    documentB = MapField(EmbeddedDocumentField(DocumentBModel)

class DocumentBModel(EmbeddedDocument):
    id = StringField(required=True)
    value = IntField()
```

A sample documentA would be as following

```
{
    id: "id_1",
    documentB: {
        0: {
            id: "b_1",
            value: 1
        },
        1: {
            id: "b_2",
            value: 11
        }
    }
```

And correspondingly, their Graphene types are

```
class DocumentB(MongoengineObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = DocumentBModel

class DocumentA(MongoengineObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = DocumentAModel
```

Finally, the query looks like the following

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    all_document_a = graphene.List(DocumentA)

    def resolve_all_document_a(self, info):
        return list(DocumentAModel.objects.all())
```

However, when I query allDocumentA to get document B, i get the error

> Object of type DocumentBModel is not JSON serializable

I am not sure where to marshal Document B to json.

If I change DocumentB from `MapField(EmbeddedDocumentField(DocumentBModel)` to `DictField()`, it works without issue. But is there a way to use MapField?

Thanks

Comment: MapField is Similar to a DictField, except the ‘value’ of each item must match the specified field type.

Comment: Yep, and I would like to enforce the value to be of type DocumentB

Comment: Having the same issue. Some progress?

Comment: Yup, I think the issue is because graphql requires the response object to have a definite structure. Having a dict or a map as an attribute "confuses" graphql.

In the example above, the query could be

query {
    documentA {
        id
        documentB {
             0 {
                 id
                 value
             }
            1 {
                 id
                 value
            }
        }
    }
}

but documentB doesnt have any attributes 0 and 1. So it just have to be a list of dicts. 

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

**MapField** is Similar to a **DictField**, except the ‘value’ of each item must match the specified field type, and keys must be String type.
So in your case DocumentAModel documentB field is MapField and type of value is DocumentBModel. So for DocumentBModel you need to provide id and value fields. You are creating this using graphene but the model mapping will be same for normal(REST) **DRF API** and **GraphQL** API. MapField has some validations like key should be String type and value should be type which you have mentioned in model, but in case of Dictfield, it does not needed such type validations, its just normal **Python Dictionary field**.

Check the code snippet. And change the **Graphene** query and schema as per requirement.

Check the following code:

```py
class DocumentBModel(fields.EmbeddedDocument):
    id = fields.StringField(required=True)
    value = fields.IntField()


class DocumentAModel(Document):
    name = fields.StringField(required=True)
    documentB = fields.MapField(fields.EmbeddedDocumentField(DocumentBModel))
```

Django shell

```py
$ python manage.py shell
>>>
>>> B_obj1 = DocumentBModel(**{'id': 'b_1', 'value': 1})
>>> B_obj2 = DocumentBModel(**{'id': 'b_2', 'value': 2})

>>> data_obj = DocumentAModel.objects.create(**{"name":"akash", "documentB":{"0":B_obj1, "1":B_obj2}})
>>> data_obj._data
{'id': ObjectId('5ebd1d2cf549becd5a462924'), 'name': 'akash', 'documentB': {'0': <DocumentBModel: DocumentBModel object>, '1': <DocumentBModel: DocumentBModel object
>}}
```

Database entry:

```py
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ebd1d2cf549becd5a462924"),
    "name" : "akash",
    "documentB" : {
        "0" : {
            "id" : "b_1",
            "value" : 1
        },
        "1" : {
            "id" : "b_2",
            "value" : 2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry if Im missing something. However, I am able to create/read Document A when I do it through python scripts. The JSON Serializable error pops up when I request it using GraphQL, which requires the response to be marshalled to JSON

Comment: you are mentioning value field in DocumentBModel and while retrieving you have count field in mongo document which is giving you conflict. as jSON serialiser error. So drop the drop the colletion and  create new using GraphQL with proper values.

Comment: Oh, apologies for that. It was a question input error. Have updated the question. Same error though

Comment: The keys needed for mapfield should be a String data types... try to change it from int to string.

Comment: Still doesnt work. Getting the same error that DocumentB is not JSON Serializable

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because graphql requires the response object to have a definite structure. Having a dict or a map as an attribute "confuses" graphql.

In the example above, the query could be

```
query {
    documentA {
        id
        documentB {
            0 {
                id
                value
            }
            1 {
                id
                value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but documentB doesnt have any attributes 0 and 1. So it just have to be a list of dicts. In which case, the query will become

```
query {
    documentA {
        id
        documentB {
            id
            value
        }
    }
}
```